# How can I get any clue how to improve the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation

I just got a downvote and close request for the [cache last function return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77973716/cache-last-function-return-value) question.

What could be wrong with this question so that I can improve further questions?

I really can't see the reasons neither for closing nor for downvoting.

I can't see the formal rules violations which could lead for closure, as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Getting concerned about a *single* downvotes is fruitless.

Comment: @ThomA, it is enough to have 3 votes for closure and it would be very hard to get the question reopened, I have experience here. So, only two shorts from the dark left here.

Comment: @ThomA, so, are you saying that the question is fine?

Comment: I didn't say that, I just said that it's *one* vote.

Comment: @ThomA, so any help on improvement?

Comment: Considering the close vote, I would suggest that opening sentence makes it look like you are asking for a library recommendation.

Comment: "Is there in C++ Standard library" is a library recommendation? I am asking about functionality in C++ **Standard** library. Am I wrong in wording?

Comment: :shrug: maybe someone felt it wasn't useful/interesting. Would knowing that help you improve the question?

Comment: @KevinB, it leads to another question, how this "shorts from the dark" help to SO? How can I guess what is wrong to react? Well, the down vote is a personal thing, but if someone voted for closure, shouldn't they put the formal official reason from rules? What is the benefit from voting without any explanations?

Comment: It helps SO by letting less than useful content sink to make content that hasn't been rated yet rise

Comment: @KevinB, this doesn't answer to my question on close requests without reasoning. And having down votes subjective, this doesn't help to reveal "less than useful" content by one downvoter as *Thom A* said at start. And... what makes this specific question "less than useful"?

Comment: Close requests *literally* come with reasoning themselves. They are called close reasons.

Comment: "And... what makes this specific question "less than useful"?" you would have to ask the downvoter. What do you think makes it a useful question?

Comment: @KevinB it is in no meaning worse than tons of questions in style "I got this homework and have no idea how to start with C++". If has justification, example of implementation and reference to existing solution for similar situation. At least, this is mature question which shows research effort and explains where we go further.

Comment: Not being worse than a bunch of other questions that are gonna be deleted in the next 60 days is a great argument

Comment: @KevinB, what kind of argument would be better for such opinion-based question like what makes it better? One could ask "What makes your comments better than..." and what kind of answer would you invent here? I am just saying that there is no good answer to this question, since it is bad like a question from a bad professor on exam in "Guess-What-I-Want-To-Hear" style.

Comment: my primary issues with your question are 1: the title is unclear, and 2: it seems weird to me for one to ask if a given thing exists in a finite list of things that anyone can look at and perform a search on. Would it not be more useful to instead ask "How do i cache the last value returned from a function" so that you're helping not only people that would like to know if X exists, *but also* actually provide a solution regardless of whether or not X exists? The only answer you received went in this direction anyway because saying "no" on it's own isn't useful to anyone else.

Comment: The answer you seemed to be expecting (based on the comments you left on the answer) would be the equivalent of looking for a solution to something and finding an "I fixed it, nevermind!" answer.

Comment: @KevinB, sorry, which one do you mean, this one or linked one?

Comment: The answer on your SO Main question

Comment: Can you give me any clue, why? Problem is stated, justified, code provided. Question is very simple: am I reinventing the wheel? If something exist, I should learn it from here, if not, I will implement. What is wrong in asking if something exist in library or can be achieved combining together existing things?

Comment: Your question title is "cache last function return value", and your question is "Does a solution for X exist in the standard library (but not ranges for reasons)". Why isn't your title closer to your question?

Comment: @KevinB, sorry, maybe this is my shortage in English, but I can't get your point here. (1) What do you mean with "(but not ranges for reasons)"? (2) How my title could be closer to the question at the same time avoiding repetition of the question, as it is required? Can you show?

Comment: It is good to repeat the question as the title. Otherwise cut the question down as little as possible for the title. In the body ask ONE (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Don't wonder. Don't ask rhetorical questions. Don't tell us that you are about to ask, just ask. Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking what the asker actually wants answered. A [mre] can be cut & pasted & run. Google your meta question using 'site:' for Q&A at [so] & [meta.se]. This meta post shows no research & is a totally generic duplicate of Q&A & [help].

Comment: I can make head nor tail from your comment. Can you please be more specific? "It is good to repeat the question as the title" - this is exactly what SO prohibits when you create the question; try to copy title to your question and get the warning. Where there are many questions in my question? Where are the rhetorical questions (like in comments you posted)? Can't get your other points at all.

Comment: An observation: C++ questions come with the bar set very high. This comes with the territory, C++ is a very mature language and thus also has a very mature repository of existing answers on Stack Overflow that should be sampled whenever possible. As such, no C++ question should contain the words *"I'm not sure if something like this already exists in the C++ Standard Library"*. Often your own choice of words tells you when a question has not had enough time in the oven yet to be ready to be posted on Stack Overflow Q&A. I have to be specific there because "discussions" now also exist.

Comment: @Gimby, good point. How would you reword the "I'm not sure if something like this already exists in the C++ Standard Library" in case if my goal is to make sure that I am not reinventing the wheel and there is no ready implementation (or known simple combination of them) to achieve the same goal?

Comment: @ThomA Indeed. One must save one's wariness for the married downvotes.

Comment: @user4581301, translate, please?

Comment: That was a play on ThomA's use of "*single* downvote". It doesn't appear to have translated well.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

1. **Questions should not have "sections"**. Explicitly separating out "justication", "code" (or as I've seen in some other cases, "background"/"context", etc. etc. etc.) is noise. A question shouldn't be long enough for these things to be useful, and if they are, then they're also making the question even longer. Aside from that: *everyone qualified to answer a question about caching knows what caching is*. You don't need to, and shouldn't try to, explain why someone might want to cache a function result. Justifications are for problem statements that are *actually strange*.
2. Questions should be about **the task, not you**. "I'm trying to..." is a reasonable way to introduce a task description. "I have this code" is a reasonable way to introduce a code block. But "I'm not sure if/whether [insert proposition about the code, language, standard library...]" is noise. Ask about that proposition directly instead.
3. **Make sure you are clear about whether this is a "why" or a "how" question**. If the question is "**why** doesn't my implementation work?", then we need a **proper MRE and a clear description of the reproducible problem** (do you get an error message? Is the result wrong?). On the other hand, if the question is "**how** do I implement this?", then we don't want to see your existing implementation in the question - *that's an answer*, and it belongs in the answer section. Instead, what we want in this case is a **clear, explicit, unambiguous specification** for the task - something that onlookers can use to determine, objectively, whether proposed answers are correct.
4. We don't do recommendations for third-party libraries. If you want to ask the how-to question, then avoid creating the impression that you're looking for someone else's already-existing code. Valid (not necessarily good) answers will include approaches like your own, as well as one-liners using the standard library (if there are any).
5. If you really are asking the how-to question (and it seems like you are), then the Q&A that @tgdavies found isn't merely a helpful suggestion - the properly asked version of your question **is clearly a duplicate** of that one.

Comment: Of course, other users can easily enough edit a question to fix *some* of these kinds of issues. But in general, it's better for everyone to *try to do that work preemptively*.